# How to eager load in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, eager-loading, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Model RunningTracks < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :achievements
  has_many :runners, through: :achievements

class Model Runner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :achievements
  has_many :running_tracks, through: :achievements

class Model Achievement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :runner
  belongs_to :running_tracks
```

On the HomePage there is an `each do` list to display all RunningTracks. Next to the track we display a button to mark it as run. An eager loading solution is an `includes` and `references` (Rails 4) in the query in the controller:

```
class RunningTracksController
  def index
    @running_tracks = RunningTracks.includes(:achievements).references(:achievements)
  end
```

To improve the usability, the button next to each record should not be visible if it had been marked. (will be refactored in an helper method)

```
@running_tracks.each do |track|
  .
  - unless track.achievements.map(&:user_id).include? current_user.id
    = button_to "done", running_track_mark_as_done_path(track)
```

This works...BUT... as the database gets more records it will query a lot of achievements, therefore a custom association and an `includes` query for only the achievements of the `current_user` (Devise) should be the solution.

```
class Model RunningTracks < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
  has_many :achieved_runns, -> { where user_id: current_user.id }, class_name "Achievement"
```

But because current_user is not accessible in the model, this does not work. I don't think its possible to pass a variable to the hay_many association, is it?

Is there a more efficient solution to do an eager loading of **all** RunningTracks including **only** the Achievements by the current user?
Thank you for your valuable time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is ugly and breaks the ActiveRecord metaphor, but would give you very fast lookups as the DB grew in size. Maybe someone else can chime in with a way to keep this within the eager-loading paradigm.

```
class RunningTrack
   # Returns a Set (for fast lookups) of track IDs that have at least one achievement for the provided user
   def self.running_track_ids_for_achievements_for_user(user_id)
      Set.new Achievement.where(:user_id => user_id).pluck(:running_track_id)
   end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
class RunningTracksController
   def index
      @running_tracks = RunningTracks.all
      @running_track_ids_for_achievements_for_user = RunningTrack.running_track_ids_for_achievements_for_user(current_user.id)
   end
end
```

And your view:

```
- unless @running_track_ids_with_achievements_for_user.include? track
   = button_to "done", running_track_mark_as_done_path(track)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is one solution I tried. but I want to list ALL RunningTracks. Unfortunately this will list only the RunningTracks that have an achievement for the current_user. The only workaround so far is to have a custom `has_many :user_achievements, -> where user_id "1", class_name: "Achievement`. Then doing a `RunningTracks.user_achievements.explain` and retrieving the sql query. I then did a find_by_sql and pasting the sql query exchanging the user ID with the current_user. This solution unfortunately is flawed, but works as long as there is only one achievement/Track.

Comment: Ok, do I understand you correctly that you want all RunningTracks, but their "achievements" association should only be populated with Achievements whose user_id is equal to the current_user.id?

Comment: yes, like I do in the console: `RunningTracks.includes(:user_achievements).references(:user_achievements)` does exactly what I want except I need to specify the user id in the Model. But there I have no access to the current_user.

Comment: Actually, the idea I was working on of filtering a LEFT OUTER JOIN isn't working, I'll have to keep thinking about this.

Comment: In this case, are you only using the achievements association to look up whether the current user has one? I have an idea for a fast way to look that up in a batch as long as you don't need the other data in `Achievement`.

Comment: Yes. In the view a list of all RunningTracks are shown. If the `current_user.signed_in`, the "mark as run" button changes its state. So Actually right now I only want to know if the current_user achieved a run. Later if required maybe a user is able to mark a RunningTrack multiple times, therefore a count should then be visible. This is not possible with my find_by_sql "hack". The "easiest" would just be to includes(:achievements) and then see for each RunningTrack if an achievement with the user_id exists. But as the DB grows bigger, that might be a performance issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: thank you Dan for this suggestion. I also thought about pluck. Yes its fast, but I then I hit the DB two times. Not that its bad, but rails provides this fantastic eager load (with scope as in "custom has_many" declaration) but no way to pass an Argument into it. Thanks again, I consider your Solution.

Comment: I'm thinking that as long as you have connection pooling, the associations might actually be slightly slower from the database perspective than the pluck approach. With Rails 3, at least, I see two queries or a left outer join when eager-loading.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thank you. Yes I did some testing! with pluck and Set.new its very fast. The only thing to figure out, is if as a future feature a Runner is able to mark a Track multiple times. Its a Rails 4 App so Pluck with two args is possible. But to check a) done/not done and b) count(or size) seems a little more tricky (at least for me, because I started programming 10 weeks ago) Thanks again (btw. it seems you missed a "def", no?)

Comment: I would think at that point just making a custom SQL query would be best, unless someone can figure out how to do it with eager loading. And I'll correct the missing `def`.

Comment: Well Dan, i think actually its not the problem with eager loading, cause it works, but with current_user not being available in the model. But I tested your solution, and I think its fast!!! Thanks